# get the number dial by Caller

Tags: voip, asterisk

I have asterisk server with assign a common voip number f.ex.:
 -  48221111111
 -  48222222222

How can i check/detect (in extension.conf) which number from this two above, the Caller dial to connect with my asterisk server?

Comment: What dose your inbound context look like?

Comment: @Mbrevda The main inboud context, looks like below: [macro-incoming_VOIP]
exten = s,1,LookupBlacklist(j)
exten = s,n,Macro(timecondition,voicemenu-custom-1|660|1,voicemenu-custom-1|660|1)
exten = s,102,Goto(Blacklist-Handle,s,1)

Comment: I tried to replace this context for below:

[macro-incoming_VOIP]
exten = s,1,LookupBlacklist(j)
exten = s,2,GotoIf("function returned dialed number" = 48221111111?3:4) // I do not know what function i should put in "function returned dialed number"
exten = s,3,Goto(from-outside|24|1)
exten = s,4,Macro(timecondition,voicemenu-custom-1|660|1,voicemenu-custom-1|660|1)
exten = s,102,Goto(Blacklist-Handle,s,1)

Comment: The topic was solved, the function which i nedded is: ${SIP_HEADER(TO)}

Answer (score 0):

You can use ${EXTEN} for that purpose or if in macro you can use ${MACRO_EXTEN}:

```
[macro-incoming_VOIP]
exten = s,1,LookupBlacklist(j)
exten = s,2,GotoIf( ${MACRO_EXTEN} = 48221111111?3:4)
exten = s,3,Goto(from-outside|24|1)
exten = s,4,Macro(timecondition,voicemenu-custom-1|660|1,voicemenu-custom-1|660|1)
exten = s,102,Goto(Blacklist-Handle,s,1)
```

If you execute a Macro than the calling extension, context, and priority are stored in ${MACRO_EXTEN}, ${MACRO_CONTEXT} and ${MACRO_PRIORITY} respectively.

Comment: thank you for your help. Topic was solved :-) Dial forwarding working now!